# Image returns to original source OnClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I have an expand and collapse system setup in jQuery/JavaScript. Once you click on the DIV the image that is within the DIV changes its state. But, when you seem to click on that DIV again, the image(s) not return back to it's original state. It is stuck in it's alternative state.

Note: I have the script in multiple instances on the same page to create an accordian effect, when you click on a different "ITEM", the image returns to the original state of the previously selected DIV.

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Dtd8/

Thank you so much!

Comment: Just a comment on the code, you may find it easier to read if your replace `jQuery` with `$`. At least it is easier to follow for me(having done a lot of jQuery, actually seeing those words distracts me).

Comment: @Kekoa: If I start all of my jQuery Statements with a dollar sign ($), there is much more room for conflict occurrences and errors. I would recommend using jQuery before each statement.

Comment: You should have no conflicts unless you load another library such as prototype which uses `$` as well. http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css to place the image in the background of the `h1` tag.  Then you can just toggle the class of the item from `.open` `.closed` to and let the css handle changing the image.

```
jQuery('.item .expandacc').click(function() {
    jQuery('.item .expandacc').not(this).removeClass("open").addClass("closed")
        .siblings('.contentacc').slideUp('normal');
    jQuery(this).next('.contentacc').slideToggle('normal');
    jQuery( this ).toggleClass("closed").toggleClass("open");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/4Dtd8/9/

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor the visibility of the content to determine which icon should be shown.

http://jsfiddle.net/4Dtd8/7/

```
jQuery('.item .expandacc').click(function() {
    if (jQuery($(this).next('.contentacc').is(':visible')) {
        jQuery('.expandacc h1 img').attr('src', 'http://www.novell.com/documentation/extend52/Docs/help/exteNd/books/GTRImages/expandIcon.png');
    }
    else {
        jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src', 'http://www.jornal.us/icons/expandIcon.jpg');
    }
    jQuery('.item .expandacc').not(this).siblings('.contentacc').slideUp('normal');
    jQuery(this).siblings('.contentacc').slideToggle('normal');
});
```

Comment: But with multiple Classes, how would one achieve what I am shooting for? For example: http://jsfiddle.net/4Dtd8/6/

Comment: Also, I think .is(':visible') will be always true because of the slide animation. http://jsfiddle.net/skram/4Dtd8/8/

Comment: @AaronBrewer - Use `next` so that it only checks the next content block. http://jsfiddle.net/4Dtd8/7/

Comment: @SKS - you are checking the the value after slideToggle has already executed. You have to use the order of operations as in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's stuck in the alternate state is this line:

```
jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src','http://www.jornal.us/icons/expandIcon.jpg');
```

No matter what state it *should* be in, this is the final code that affects the image's source. So the source is always set to what is specified in that line.

Comment: SO what do you suggest I do to fix this issue? To have the image return to it's original state after a different DIV CLASS is selected, but still keep the image in the alternative state while that class is selected? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I added a custom attr `isExpanded` for the image tag to save if it is expanded or collapsed and checked the value to find its state.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/4Dtd8/4/) here

jQuery('.item .expandacc').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).siblings('.contentacc').slideToggle('normal');

```
    var $img = jQuery(this).find('img');
    var isExpanded = $img.attr('isExpanded');

    // For some browsers, `isExpanded` is undefined; for others,
    // `isExpanded` is false.  Check for both.
    if (typeof isExpanded === 'undefined' || 
            isExpanded === false || 
                 isExpanded == 'true') {
        $img.attr('src', 'http://www.jornal.us/icons/expandIcon.jpg');

        $img.attr('isExpanded', 'false');
    } else {
        $img.attr('src', 'http://www.novell.com/documentation/extend52/Docs/help/exteNd/books/GTRImages/expandIcon.png');

        $img.attr('isExpanded', 'true');
    }
```